# How to remove these red lines in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

[image]

Hi I wonder if there is a way I can get rid of these red lines in Adobe Illustrator? I can't seem to find where to disable them

Answer (score 1):

You or the maker of the image has (maybe accidentally) drawn some slices. If it was not an accident you can make them invisible by selecting Hide Slices in the View menu.

In the next example I have drawn one path (=the grey rectangle) and one slice.

[image]

Slices are drawn by using the Slice tool. Slices occur in the layers panel as objects. It's here the object named Slice. It's selected and the selection occurs as a colored square in the layers panel.

Select your unwanted slices in the layers panel (click the circle, see how the square appears) or by clicking with the slice selection tool (it's hidden below the Slice tool) and press DEL.

To know more of slicing see the documentation. Start for ex. here https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/illustrator/using/slicing-cutting-tool-gallery.html